# how to add a slash to all the lines content in the excel?

Tags: excel, vba, xls

```
image
UploadPic/2012-02-08/132168689584.jpg
UploadPic/2012-02-08/132168689539.jpg
UploadPic/2012-02-08/132168689579.jpg
UploadPic/2012-02-08/132168689580.jpg
UploadPic/2012-02-08/132168689659.jpg
UploadPic/2012-02-08/132168689698.jpg
UploadPic/2012-02-08/132168689611.jpg
UploadPic/2012-02-08/132168689621.jpg
UploadPic/2012-02-08/132168689610.jpg
UploadPic/2012-02-08/132168689658.jpg
```

there is a column (img)like the above, now i want to add a slash before `UploadPic`(/UploadPic) and do it with a batch. how do i do?

Comment: `"//" + mystring`. Need *cooodeeee!* *Cooodddeeeee!* `</code_zombie>`

Comment: i am sorry i don't know what's your answer meaning

Comment: i am sorry, i am a newbie, i don't know where to code in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple little macro will do that to every used cell in column A:

```
Sub AddSlash()
Dim MyRNG As Range, cell As Range

Set MyRNG = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlConstants)

    For Each cell In MyRNG
        cell.Value = "/" & cell.Value
    Next cell

End Sub
```

*How/Where to install the macro:*

1. Open up your workbook
2. Get into VB Editor *(Press Alt+F11)*
3. Insert a new module *(Insert > Module)*
4. Copy and Paste in your code *(given above)*
5. Get out of VBA *(Press Alt+Q)*
6. Save as a macro-enabled workbook

The macro is installed and ready to use. Press **Alt-F8** and select it from the macro list.

Answer (score 3):

```
control + f
```

Replace tab

Find what:  "UploadPic"
Replace with: "\UploadPic"

Click - Replace All

I like to take a little extra text in the Find What just to be sure.